# Fix URL of Secondly Created List

Tags: 2010, list

I created a list called *Tickets* and then renamed it to *Tickets Old*.  Then I created a new list called Tickets.

Now the url has `http://my.portal.com/tickets1`

How can I fix that without deleting the list and recreating it?  I've deleted *Tickets Old*.

(I have [Sharepoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/97332) if that helps any)

Comment: Check this: https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/change-the-url-of-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Designer.  The trick is to navigate to "Site Objects" > "All Files" and find your library.  Right click on your library and rename.  This will change the URL path that you are looking to update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if SharePoint Manager can change the URL of existing lists, but what I would do if the list wasn't too big or complex is make a template of it (including content), delete the existing list and then recreate it using the template. You can then delete the template if you don't need it.

Comment: Hmmm..  I thought of that too, actually. That's not a bad idea if there is no other way.